# What do you call one of the first members of a club or organization?

Tags: phrase-requests

I've heard of this position being called a pioneer member or charter member, but to me those imply that that member founded the organization. I didn't found this group, but once it became an offical organization, I was one of the first to join it.

Comment: An apostle? Oops, wrong Stack Exchange, but how about a __founding father__

Comment: I don’t take *charter member* to be the founder but merely one of the original members.

Comment: _The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language_, fifth edition (2011) has this entry for _charter member_: "**charter member** _n._ An original member or a founder of an organization." So the term can mean _founder_ but it can just as legitimately mean "an original member"—which is what you want. The founder of an organization is usually a charter member, too, so separating the two roles isn't easy; but the fact that the founder can be called "the founder" makes it more likely (in my judgment) that someone identified as "a charter member" is a nonfounder—else, why not use "founder"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jim is correct.  A charter member is simply [*an original member of a group*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charter%20member).  The term doesn't imply any particular responsibility.  If you joined shortly after the group was formed but were not an original member, you could be called an "early" member.

Answer (score 0):

Inaugural might be another option.

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inaugural) gives as the second definition:

> 1
> : of or relating to an inauguration
>
> 2
> : marking a beginning : first in a projected series

Comment: Hi Melissa, I've tried to help by adding a citation, and I encourage you to justify your answer as detailed in the [help].

Answer (score -1):

**Pioneer** ?
**V.:** To take part in the beginnings of; initiate.
To lead the way for (a group); guide.
 To initiate, prepare, or open up: to pioneer a medical programme. 
 **N** One who is first or among the earliest in any field of inquiry, enterprise, or progress.

Comment: Please take the time to format your answer like the dictionary did. And please provide the cite and link to this dictionary.